# Cannot update Firebase realtime database and change text color AT THE SAME TIME under the same .addEventListender()

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having a simple JS function :

When I click to the `<li> itemValue <li>`, it will:

1. update the Firebase values from Yes/NO to NO/Yes
2. change the color of the `<li> itemValue <li>` by using `.SetAttribute`

The issue here is the 2 functions above cannot work together at the same time. Each one works perfectly without the other.
If I remove the update Firebase, the change color function will work and if I remove the change color, update Firebase will work.

How do I make them both working under the same click? Or this is a bug from Firebase?

```
 
        let newEl = document.createElement("li") 
        
        newEl.textContent = itemValue 
           
        newEl.addEventListener("click", function() {

            let attendant = ref(database, `shoppingList/${i}/`)
            if (itemAtt === "No") {
            newEl.setAttribute("class","green")
            update((attendant), {  "Att": "Yes"  })
             itemAtt = "Yes" 
            }
            
            else if (itemAtt === "Yes")   {
            newEl.setAttribute("class","red")
            update((attendant), {  "Att": "No"  }) 
            itemAtt = "No"     
  
            }

           
        }) 
        
        shoppingListEl.append(newEl)
```

I hope I can make them both working under the same click

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like so:

```
newEl.addEventListener("click", function() {
    let attendant = ref(database, `shoppingList/${i}/`);

    if (itemAtt === "No") {
        // Update Firebase data
        update(attendant, { "Att": "Yes" })
            .then(() => {
                newEl.setAttribute("class", "green");
                itemAtt = "Yes";
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error("Error updating Firebase:", error);
            });
    } else if (itemAtt === "Yes") {
        // Update Firebase data
        update(attendant, { "Att": "No" })
            .then(() => {
                newEl.setAttribute("class", "red");
                itemAtt = "No";
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error("Error updating Firebase:", error);
            });
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Mo, thank you for your response. I applied your code and it still only update my Firebase values, it still not apply to change the color.